# How to properly layout an edit text horizontally in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I am trying to figure how I can properly layout an edit text in between two views so that It will take up the whole width nicely in all screen sizes.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/country_india"/>
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Leave a comment"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_pencil_2_small"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using `android:layout_weight="1"` instead of fixing the width if you'd like to fit the `EditText` to fit in.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/country_india"/>

    <EditText
        android:hint="Leave a comment"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pencil_2_small"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ah that helped a lot thanks mate. So what is "weight?"

Comment: basically weight only works with LinearLayouts either horizontal or vertical, it tells the Layout to weight either height or width base on the layout orientation to the specific weight, for example to align three stuff while fixing their size to be the same u should be using on each view of weight 1. so all the views under the linearLayout will have the same size

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/country_india"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Leave a comment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pencil_2_small"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: don't write only `code` add description to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this below code

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
          >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
               />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Leave a comment"
                android:layout_weight="3"
               />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: don't write only `code` add description to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add android:layout_weight="1" to editText

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/country_india"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Leave a comment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pencil_2_small"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way if I were you. Populate the weight and you're good to go.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1.5">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/country_india"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Leave a comment"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_pencil_2_small"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your `Edittext` `layout_weight="1"`in the middle of 2 `ImageView` (or something):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="72dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/address_item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_black_background"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="This is an edit text"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/address_item_arrow_image_view"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/messenger_bubble_large_blue"/>

</LinearLayout>
```